# naming n-dimensional triangulation

Tags: triangulation

I wonder why a triangulation of an n-dimensional point set is called triangulation and not something like "simplicication". Formally, the name of "triangles" is only used for 3-simplices and actually triangle itself is rarely used.

Is there any other formal term other than "triangulation"?

Thank you.

Comment: The term simplicialization seems to be occasionally used.

Comment: Since it's even used for non-simple shapes (Think of NURBS or T-spline surfaces), I hardly believe in any other term. Plus, "simpliciation" is a whole lot harder to pronounce and write than "triangulation". Also note that n-simplices also consist of triangles as their 2D-faces, so the term is not wrong for $n>1$

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Do you have any reference? I'd be interested because I have only seen triangulation in literature and papers alike.

Comment: @AlexR after looking for "simplicialization" in Google some papers appear.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip if you post it as an answer I will be happy to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @JaviV I could only find [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1134%2FS1054661809020035) topology related one and [this](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~mari/Recherche/Articles/assets/mari_ctic2008.pdf) plus a book "Progress in Pattern Recognition, ...". Seems rarely used. About $400$ results vs. $1,700,000$ for "triangulation"

Comment: @AlexR there are very hidden ones: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.0405.pdf
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X04003658

Comment: @JaviV Thanks for the references, you may want to add them to the answer to back it up ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term simplicialization seems to be occasionally used.

Comment: For instance:  
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.0405.pdf


http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X04003658